# IPad's stock selection area conflict with custom div overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

I'm new to develop iPad development. I have encountered a prob here. I have a feature in my app in which when user selects any text, a overlay appears on the screen. The prob is when the text is selected the overlay appears but the blue selection area of text appears over the new overlay. I tried giving z-index to my overlay but it doesn't work. Anyone who has come across such issue or ipad dev guys please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Because text selection is a function of  native app (browser) and you are working on web app that is inside browser(native app) therefore you can not create any layer upon native app.**

Comment: is it possible to clear selection using javascript/jQuery in ipad